# How to create this shape drawable

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml, android-drawable

I want to create xml drawable to this shape,

[image]

Comment: wouldn't it be better to use 9 patch image ?

Comment: For this kind of complex shape its batter to use image as 9 patch image https://developer.android.com/studio/write/draw9patch.html

Comment: resolve the issues using 9 patch image, thanks Pankaj and Ajay

Answer (score 2):

use this layout and save in drawable folder.....

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <size
                android:width="200dp"
                android:height="50dp" />
            <solid android:color="#ef45d1" />
            <corners android:topRightRadius="20dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>


    <item
        android:bottom="0dp"
        android:right="165dp"
        android:top="0dp">

        <rotate
            android:fromDegrees="45"
            android:pivotX="0%"
            android:pivotY="0%"
            android:toDegrees="45">

            <shape android:shape="rectangle">
                <solid android:color="#ffffff" />


            </shape>
        </rotate>

    </item>

</layer-list>
```

and set in your layout view as background....

```
<Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button"
        android:background="@drawable/newrecatngle"/>
```

NOTE:-**set width and height as wrap_content**.....

[image]

enjoy coding...........

Comment: Thanks for the effort sushildlh, but the i need to make the white triangle transparent, is it possible to do something like that..

Comment: just change color of this into your background `<solid android:color="#ffffff" />`

Comment: when i do that, bottom pink square part will appear, i wont to make it transparent without doing that.

Comment: you have to use your background color there ....don't use transparent color there .............  first one is rectangle button and on that button arrow of white color ....and you have to change arrow color