# Create a flow-chart-arrow-styled-button

Tags: android, xml

how can I create an button which looks like this:

```
\--------------\
  \              \
    \   MY-        \
    /   BUTTON     /
  /              /
/--------------/
```

I managed to create the arrow-style for the right side, but it seems like I am not able to design the left site of the button...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
  <item>
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
      <size
          android:width="200dp"
          android:height="150dp" />
      <solid android:color="#5EB888" />
      <corners android:radius="10dp"/>
    </shape>
  </item>
  <item
      android:top="-40dp"
      android:bottom="65dp"
      android:right="-250dp">
    <rotate
        android:fromDegrees="45">
      <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <solid android:color="#3F51B5" />
      </shape>
    </rotate>
  </item>
  <item
      android:top="65dp"
      android:bottom="-40dp"
      android:right="-250dp">
    <rotate
        android:fromDegrees="-45">
      <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <solid android:color="#3F51B5" />
      </shape>
    </rotate>
  </item>
</layer-list>
```

Hopefully you guys can help me :)

Cheers!

Comment: use this for the left side http://stackoverflow.com/a/37829398/5305430

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, I managed to solve the problem, thanks to @sushildlh's comment:
(Note: Button height: 200; width: 350)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
  <item>
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
      <size
          android:width="200dp"
          android:height="150dp" />
      <solid android:color="#5EB888" />
      <corners android:radius="0dp"/>
    </shape>
  </item>

  <item
    android:top="0dp"
    android:bottom="0dp"
    android:right="205dp"
    android:left="0dp">
    <rotate
        android:fromDegrees="45"
        android:pivotX="0%"
        android:pivotY="0%"
        android:toDegrees="45">
      <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <solid android:color="#3F51B5" />
      </shape>
    </rotate>
  </item>

  <item
      android:top="-40dp"
      android:bottom="65dp"
      android:right="-400dp">
    <rotate
        android:fromDegrees="45">
      <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <solid android:color="#3F51B5" />
      </shape>
    </rotate>
  </item>
  <item
      android:top="65dp"
      android:bottom="-40dp"
      android:right="-400dp">
    <rotate
        android:fromDegrees="-45">
      <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <solid android:color="#3F51B5" />
      </shape>
    </rotate>
  </item>
</layer-list>
```